# When MongoDB fail to connect it crashes the app although it's surrounded with a Promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

When i run it with a correct password it works fine, only with an incorrect password it throws an uncuaght exception which is not caught by the promise for some reason, and then the app crash

Here is the controller **tryCtrl.js**:

```
const connection = require('./tryDB');

connection
  .then(() => console.log('success'))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Here is the model file that access the db **tryDB.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

// create connection to db
const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;

const connection = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  mongoose.connect(uri);
  const db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', (error) => {
    reject(error);
  });
  db.once('open', () => {
    resolve(db);
  });
});

module.exports = connection;
```

when i run it with a false password i expect the expection to be caught, but it breaks the app
Here is the error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^

MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\israe\Documents\GitHub\my-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:201:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\israe\Documents\GitHub\my-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:59:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\israe\Documents\GitHub\my-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:124:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\israe\Documents\GitHub\my-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28) {   ok: 0,   code: 8000,   codeName: 'AtlasError',   connectionGeneration: 0,  
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' } }
```

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit when i run it with a correct password it works smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you shouldn't export variables that refer to `Promises`. Exports are meant for functionality or constants which you intend to reuse later. You should restructure your `connection` function, to return a `Promise` instead, like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

// create connection to db
const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;

const connection = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  mongoose.connect(uri);
  const db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', (error) => {
    reject(error);
  });
  db.once('open', () => {
    resolve(db);
  });
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Now your controller becomes like this:

```
const connection = require('./tryDB');

connection()
  .then(() => console.log('success'))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Note, that I have called the `connection` function first, then the promise functions are chained.

UPDATE: This is an uncaught exception. To catch it, you can add `process.on` event handlers. In your app.js file, like this:

```
process
  .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
  })
  .on('uncaughtException', err => {
    console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
  });
```

Note this is not the recommended way, ideally, you should let the application stop on such errors. Also, you can try setting `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` as suggested by the creator of mongoose [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3355).

Comment: Thank you, your logic sound right, but i have tested it, and it still throws the same uncuaught exeption

Comment: is this snipper suppose to be added to the controller after the call to connection() ?

Comment: no, it should be in the main file, where the server is created

Comment: Ok thank you, that's a nice bypass, but i still don't understand why the reject don't catch it, i thought it was the point of reject

Comment: Yeah, I have added a minor update as well. Please check it out.